# What to put in DisplayUrl in AdMob promotion?

Tags: android, admob, promotions

I know it sounds and actually is stupid. I am trying to promote my app with AdMob. In the promotion form there, I put

```
 URL: market://details?id=com.xxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx
 DisplayUrl: ????
```

Whatever I enter for DisplayUrl, system is giving me invalid format error.

I have read the guidelines http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/content-guidelines#displayURL but it does not help at all. Can someone help me?

UPDATE: I fed up with that option Text & Tile and went with image option with which I can upload my own image and be done with it. So much for 1 cent/click saved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't know if this helps you, but I was having the exact same problem, which I might add, was very frustrating! :-P

I believe what they're looking for, for that field (which they should really explain BETTER), is they want a url to a website, that a desktop browser can go to.  Like for example...

```
       URL: market://details?id=com.xxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxx
DisplayUrl: play.google.com/store
```

Now please keep in mind, I tried adding both `http://` and `https://` and got the same

`There were problems with your submission.` and `Invalid Display URL format.` error

I know that fixed my problem! :-)

Honestly, since I'm sure at least 60% of ads are to the Google Play Store, I think they should really suggest that, or maybe give an alternative suggestion.  Since they are such sticklers on the format, they should give us more guidance, and maybe an example? :-P

I hope that fixes your problem :-)

Comment: Thanks. I will try your suggestion sometime soon.

Comment: Did that fix it for you Paul?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it would appear that the DisplayUrl is specifying the location of a html document that is to be retrieved and displayed in the ad box. Do you get a webpage at the url that you are putting in this option if you view it in a normal web browser? Also, have you given your app permission to the internet?

**Updated**

Also, here are the directions on adding a mobile site or Android app: http://helpcenter.admob.com/content/add-your-mobile-site-or-android-app

Comment: Yeah, everything in my side is functional. Problem is that Display Url does not work whatever is entered. I am suspecting it is implicitly intended